# Test is not entering rxjs operator pipe and tap in the Angular code

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, tap, rxjs-observables

My test is not able to cover the pipe part of the code, don't know what's wrong. [covereage of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kivuD.png). I am using ngx-chip in the template. The autocompleteObservable picks the text typed in the tag-input and is passed it to the requestAutocompleteItems, further it is passed to peopleService to get data based on the text. There is also a spinner that is manually turned on and off before and after the data is processed.

component.html

```
<tag-input
  theme="foundation-theme"
  [placeholder]="placeholder"
  [secondaryPlaceholder]="secondPlaceholder"
  onlyFromAutocomplete="true"
  [animationDuration]="animation"
  [(ngModel)]="items"
  (onAdd)="onItemAdded($event)"
  (onRemove)="onItemRemoved()"
  [maxItems]="maxItems"
  (focusout)="stopLoading()"
>
  <tag-input-dropdown
    [autocompleteObservable]="requestAutocompleteItems"
    [dynamicUpdate]="false"
    [displayBy]="fieldName"
    [identifyBy]="fieldId"
    [minimumTextLength]="numberText"
    [appendToBody]="false"
  >
  </tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>
<div class="progress-spinner" *ngIf="showLoading">
  <p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.requestAutocompleteItems = (text: string): Observable<AutoCompleteItem[]> => {
      this.showLoading = true;
      // Add this to an autocomplete
      let textJson;
      if (this.department) {
        textJson = {
          where: { and: [{ displayName: { like: text } }, { department: { like: this.department } }] },
          include: this.colsIncluded,
        };
      } else {
        textJson = { where: { displayName: { like: text } }, include: this.colsIncluded };
      }
      return this.peopleService.getData(JSON.stringify(textJson)).pipe(
        tap(() => {
          this.showLoading = false;
        }),
      );
    };
  }
```

component.spec.ts

```
it('should stop loading', () => {
    peoplePickerServiceSpy.getData.and.returnValue(of({}));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.requestAutocompleteItems('erv');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(peoplePickerServiceSpy.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: It's not clear from your code where do you actually subscribe to `requestAutocompleteItems`. Is it used somewhere inside the template?

Comment: @mat.hudak I have added more to the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed the issue just as Mat said it needs a subscribe block to complete the observable I added a done function.

```
it('should stop loading', done => {
    peoplePickerServiceSpy.getData.and.returnValue(of({}));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.requestAutocompleteItems('erv').subscribe(() => {
      expect(peoplePickerServiceSpy.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is lacking subscription to the `requestAutocompleteItems`. If nothing subscribes to it the code in the `tap` operator will never fire. So you either provide a `tag-input` mock which is capable of doing that, or do it without it. And this is a good question for experts, whether we care about how is our observable treated in some child component, or we don't.

If you decide you don't worry about it, you should wrap your unit test to `fakeAsync` function and then subscribe to `requestAutocompleteItems` within UT.

```typescript
it('should stop loading', fakeAsync(() => {
  peoplePickerServiceSpy.getData.and.returnValue(of({}));
  fixture.detectChanges();

  component.requestAutocompleteItems('erv').subscribe(() => {
    expect(peoplePickerServiceSpy.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  fixture.detectChanges();

  tick(); //necessary -> simulates the asynchronous passage of time
}));
```